# react-bootstrap displaces the other content in React JS application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have created s sample react bootstrap modal box, basically same code as at:- http://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#modals-live. The model is its own component which I have added to another component as child. Modal comes up fine but it displaces rest of the content that exists on that page, when it should appear on top of the page. Not sure what I might be doing wrong. The parent component is as below:-

```
<div className="detail-sctions">
    <TestModal closeModel = {this.closeTestModal.bind(this)} showModal={this.state.showModel}/>

      <ul className="tabs nav-backs">
          <li className="tab-title nav-backs"><button onClick={}>tab1</button></li>
          <li className="tab-title nav-backs active"><button>tab1</button></li>
          <li className="tab-title nav-backs"><button>tab3</button></li>
          <li className="tab-title nav-backs"><button onClick={}>tab4</button></li>
          <li className="tab-title nav-backs"><button>tab5</button></li>
      </ul>
 </div>
```

here TestModal is the sample code from that link.

Comment: Just a remark, you have many places where you call `modal` `model` maybe it breaks something somewhere...

Comment: those are variables and functions nothing related to Modal component

Answer (score 0):

from react bootstrap forum on github, I go to know that bootstrap css is a must to make it work like examples. So after adding the bootstrap css it works fine.